# How to set this Layout in iPhone need Some help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have Implement Some paint like application. For that the Layout is like as below:
[image]

Here, there is One View and two buttons. In My application i am selecting the colour from Button2 and then doing drawing on View.
But the Problem is while i am selecting the Colour and if i do the Paint on the View, all works file but if that paint come over the Button1, it also paint on that button1. I want set as like that the selection colour Should not be paint on the Button1 and only paint on the View.
So for that What Should i have to do ?
I want to set the Button1 in front of the View and do not allow to paint on it.
please Guide me proper regarding this mater.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing the actual painting?

Comment: I am selecting the Colour from the Button2 and then touch on the ImageView(view) i drow the colour of selected button2.

Comment: Can we see some code where you are actually doing the drawing? Its possible you may be drawing on the wrong view, or something to do with your view hierarchy.

Comment: I am not able to put the code here. Sorry for that. But i think i am right with the Programming part. If there are only View problem then what should be the Problem  ?

Comment: I think should make one more view lets say btnview and in that put your button. When doing painting do only on main view not on btnview.

Comment: are you sure the view you are painting to is the button 2? are you able to tap button 2?

Comment: Yes, I am able to tap on Button2. And the View on which i am @lukya: painting is done only on the View Part. But while i am painting, it is also painted on the Button1 and button2. And i want to paint it only on the view. I have taken View as ImageView abd it is set by Programmeticaly..

Comment: if the buttons are added in xib and the image view is being added in code using addSubview it will be on top of the buttons not below them.. see @WolfLink's answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure your buttons are not subviews of the view you are drawing in.

The simplest way to do this is to organize your buttons and your view in interface builder so that you have a UIView within your window as well as your buttons which must be on a higher layer than your UIView but cannot be inside your UIView.  I would post pictures if the site would let me.  You will then need to make a UIView IBOutlet to attatch to the UIView in Interface Builder and to draw to in your code.

To do this programmatically, after you have created your buttons, create a UIView and add it as a subview to your viewController's view by using (if myView is your UIView)

```
[self.view addSubview:myView]
```

and then use

```
[self.view send SubviewToBack:myView]
```

to make sure it is behind your other subviews (your buttons).  Draw to myView and it should appear behind the buttons.