# Problem regarding draw image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set this Layout in iPhone need Some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411496/how-to-set-this-layout-in-iphone-need-some-help)

I draw image in imageview.

[image]

I have one image view and Button is there.

When i draw something it show like this,

[image]

I dont wan't to show drawing on that button.

How can i do that?

Comment: Please post details of method you used for drawing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

1) You can do this IB:

Drag your `UIImageView` in IB to bottom of your stack subviews of view where your `UIView` (where you are drawing) is placed.

[image: Stack of subviews]

2) You can do this in code:

Push your view on the top of views using following method

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

For example:

```
UILabel * labelgreen;
[labelgreen.superview bringSubviewToFront:labelgreen];
```